# Extending jQuery UI methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-framework

I'm looking to see if it's possible to add methods or interactions to the jQuery UI library without editing the code itself? I want to be able to quickly upgrade as new versions come out, but still be able to add my own features that extend the base UI script.

Example:

I want to use the .dialog() method to have pointer tips to provide messaging to specific areas.

Is there an easy way to add this, or will I end up having to download the source and do it myself each time a release comes out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access the UI widget's prototype:

```
var proto = $.ui.autocomplete.prototype;

proto.myNewMethodForAutocomplete = function(){
    // ...
};
```

You can also directy extend the prototype like this: [How to extend a jquery ui widget ? (1.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525247/how-to-extend-a-jquery-ui-widget-1-7/2813259#2813259)