# jQuery UI event functionality extending

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, inheritance, extending

I want to add functionality of auto-destroying dialog on close without adding any special code to every dialog call in the current project. So I think it needs to override the default dialog `close` event.

I found a way to do this (for example: [How to extend a jquery ui widget ? (1.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525247/how-to-extend-a-jquery-ui-widget-1-7/2813259)), but I don't want just override the event: I also need to save the previous behavior of the event and add `$(this).dialog("destroy")` call after it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You must save a destroy handler first, that run your own, and then saved one.
How do you manage to override this handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about the correctness of this, but I think you can safely override the close method like this:

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype._originalClose = $.ui.dialog.prototype.close;
$.ui.dialog.prototype.close = function() {
        alert ('My stuff');
        $.ui.dialog.prototype._originalClose.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

You can see this working at: http://jsfiddle.net/8KKMm/

*However*, it's normally a good idea to avoid overriding external libraries. There might be better ways to achieve your target without mangling with jQuery UI library. Please do have a look at the available events of the Dialog component: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/.

Comment: Thanks, works fine. And, yes, it will be better to use events. Anyway, also would like to know how to call inside overrided method 'destroy' or 'open' of self? TIA.

Comment: I think you can simply call `this.destroy()` within that context. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/8KKMm/2/ .

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `dialogclose` handler to the `body` element of the page.

You can find a sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y2VNN/).

There is no need to override the close function of the dialog class, you can simply use the events provided by the dialog class.

Ex:

```
$("body").on("dialogclose", function(){
    alert("closed");
});
```